# Install AApanel and Swizzin Seedbox

Tags: 18.04

Can I install AAPanel together with Swizzin? I tried install Swizzin first. It was working. I can access the Swizzin panel through my VPS IP address. But after I install AAPanel, Swizzin stopped working.

Any guide please? OS: Ubuntu 18.04 Thanks.